# Multiple module.exports in a node js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

How does the Nodejs engine decides when a file has multiple `module.exports` and it is being required by another file ?
How does the final closure is being calculated ?

Comment: If it has multiple `module.exports` assignments then all previous ones get overwritten by the last one.

Comment: The same way as any other assignment to a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the value that `module.exports` has when the execution of the module has finished:

```
module.exports = { foo: 'bar' };
module.exports = { a: 17.8 };    // overwrite "module.exports"
module.exports = 5;              // and again 
module.exports = { b: 123 };     // and again
```

Now, when you require the module, you will get `{ b: 123 }`.

`module.exports` is not a magic keyword, it's just a variable that you can set to tell NodeJS what should be exported.

Comment: Say you wanted to combine two variables/functions into one export. Would something like `module.exports = {funcA, funcB}` work?